# Generated model from database - explicit primary key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a from database generated model in Entity Framework with VS.NET 2012 (.NET 4.5).

When I try to insert an explicit primary key it ignores the explicit value and generates a new one. I need to migrate from an old database so saving old primary keys is a must.

How can I set an explicit value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to enable and disable explicit identity insert. Don't forget to disable it when you are done.

Comment: Before _context.SaveChanges() or right before _context.Set<Example>.Add(entity). And should I call it with ExecuteSqlCommand method? Thank you.